# Help with finding a pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm currently working through a programming book and on one of the projects, I've hit a snag.  I'm trying to avoid using a "magic number" solution and I am having trouble finding the relationship between a sequence of numbers.

Essentially the output needs to be as follows.

If the input is 10...

```
|----****----|
```

The |'s and the *'s are a constant size, the only thing changing based on the input is the -'s.

Below is a table of how they change based on the input.

Input is X, left -'s Y, right -'s z

```
 X   Y   Z  Output

 9   2   3  |--****---|
10   4   4  |----****----|
11   5   6  |-----****------|
12   7   7  |-------****-------|
13   8   9  |--------****---------|
14  10  10  |----------****----------|
15  11  12  |-----------****------------|
16  13  13  |-------------****-------------|
```

Any help finding the relationship would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

**EDIT**

Solution based on @Bananarama's answer:

```
int x, y, z    

y = ((x / 2) * 3) - (11 - (x % 2))
z = ((x / 2) * 3) - (11 - ((x % 2) * 2))
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know the output for each input. What do you want?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear.  I'm trying to figure out a formula that states, if X is this, than Y and Z are this.  I need Y and Z to change based on input X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently if the input is $2n$ you get $3n-11$ bars to the left and $3n-11$ bars to the right.

If the input is $2n+1$ we seem to get $3n-10$ bars to the left and $3n-9$ bars to the right.